# REST API Recurring payment appearing in sandbox, but nothing transferred

Tags: rest, paypal, recurring

I've set up and executed recurring payments via REST API. It all appears in the users sandbox account, but amount sent is always 0, both initial payment and daily recurrences.

Any ideas?

Thanks

```
| Payment type | Amount due each cycle  | Total cycles |    Remaining cycles    | Cycle frequency   | Amount sent 
| Initial Payment | £25.00 GBP |    -- |    --  | --    | £0.00 GBP
| Regular Recurring Payment | £130.60 GBP  | Indefinite |   Indefinite |    Daily   | £0.00 GBP
|   |                                                                  | Total £0.00 GBP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, turns out the sandbox doesn't work. The exact same code run on the live site works perfectly.